# How to saveinstace of a MediaPlayer on a Bundle (android)

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I need to save the instance of MediaPlayer so when my activity is restarted I can regain control over the Media Player that is running.

So how can I pass it to the Bundle? putSerializable() doesn't work. Maybe using putIBinder() works, but I don't know if its right to do like that.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong approach.  Please read the documentation for MediaPlayer and controlling it's state, then think again about your design.  If you want sound to continue playing when your app is in the background, then use a background service.  If you don't, then save it's state (track, current position etc) in SharedPreferences in onPause() and reinitialise in onResume()

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I pass it to the Bundle?

You can't.

> I need to save the instance of MediaPlayer so when my activity is restarted I can regain control over the Media Player that is running.

If by "restarted", you only are concerned about configuration changes within one activity, use a retained fragment (i.e., a fragment on which you have called `setRetainInstance(true)`) to manage your `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Do you think this is the "best" to do that? Or do you think that creating a service and placing MediaPlayer on it, is better.

Comment: @user3288348: That depends upon your objective. If you only plan to use the `MediaPlayer` in this one activity, retaining the `MediaPlayer` per my answer is fine. If you need to have the media playback span activities, or work when your UI is not in the foreground, then a `Service` is pretty much essential.